# Objective-C const NSString * vs NSString * const

Tags: objective-c, constants

I'm trying to a NSString constant in my .h file to be defined in my .m. I understand that
`extern NSString * const variableName;` in the .h and
`NSString * const variableName = @"variableValue";` is the way to do this.  Examining C tutorials I see that `const` is supposed to go before variable definitions.  My question is why is it not declared as `extern const NSString * variableName;` in the .h and `const NSString * variableName = @"variableValue";` in the .m.  I know this doesn't work because I encounter compiler warnings which say 'Passing argument 1 of methodName: discards qualifiers from pointer target type'.  What does this mean?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It's not the same. The const modifier can be applied to the value, or the pointer to the value.

---

```
int * const
```

A constant pointer (not modifiable) to an integer (its value can be modified)

---

```
const int *
```

A modifiable pointer to a constant integer (its value can't be modified)

---

So you can imagine:

```
const int * const;
```

Comment: To expand on that, if you're not dealing with a pointer, `const int` and `int const` are exactly the same. `NSString`s are already immutable, so the const only needs to be applied to the pointer (which can be a little confusing since Objective-C objects are always accessed via pointers).

Comment: @Macmade why didn't you explain this in terms of NSString since the syntax is different anyways with the pointer?

Comment: To expand on that, `const int *` and `int const *` are the same, but `int * const` is different.

Comment: @Wevah: "NSStrings are already immutable" but an NSString pointer can still point to an NSMutableString

Answer (score 6):

Constant pointer is NOT a pointer to constant. Constant pointer means the pointer is constant. E.g. constant pointer `int * const ptr2;` indicates that `ptr2` is a pointer which is constant. This means that `ptr2` cannot be made to point to another integer. However, the integer pointed by `ptr2` can be changed.

Whereas a pointer to constant `const int * ptr1;` indicates that `ptr1` is a pointer that points to a constant integer. The integer is constant and cannot be changed. However, the pointer `ptr1` can be made to point to some other integer.